# How to launch live site source code in local environment in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have imported live project source code in visual studio and tried to set up locally, but when I tried to launch an application it is redirecting to a live site rather than localhost.

Below are the steps, I followed.

- Imported source code from the live site into the Visual Studio.
- Set Index.asp, as a start page.
- Then click on the 'IIS Express' button to launch an application.

But it is redirecting to live site, rather than localhost.

Answer (score 1):

In *Visual Studio*, in *Solution Explorer* on the right side of screen, find the *startup project* inside the *solution*. That is the project with **bold** name.

[image]

Right click on it and choose *Properties*. Then choose card *Web* and change *Project Url* to

`localhost:[some_port]`.

[image]